# Using 301 redirect inside htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301, redirect

I used to have a link like:
`www.domain.com/index.php?id=IdParameter&place=true`
But I don't use `"place=true"` anymore.
I want all those links to look like:
`www.domain.com/index.php?id=IdParameter`

WITHOUT the `"&place=true"` part.
How can I redirect links including `"place=true"` to themselves, without that last part?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?)&place=true$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [L,R]
```